# Display text based on info selected in two drop downs

Tags: jquery, html, forms, conditional-statements, dropdownbox

I need to write a quick bit of code that allows users at the top of one of our article pages to do the following:

`Drop down 1: How old are you?`

`Drop down 2: What's your favourite fruit?`

Based on inputs above, summary text instantly displays below after the second selection is made, based on both selections above e.g.

For 18-24 year olds who like apples: Apples help you build your immune system at your age!

For 50-60 year olds who like bananas: Bananas really help with vitamin C and bone density in later life.

Comment: What about vice versa options? like 18-24 years old and selects banana, and 50-60 years old and selects apple? Also what are the options for how old are you.. Add some code buddy..

Comment: Add the code...u tried

Comment: I don't have any code yet, guys. Everything I've found on SO or the web has referenced COPYING the inputs in the text output, and then only separately. 

In the example of 50 and bananas, the output would simply be: You are <1> and like <2>. I'm trying to provide a result based on combinations of both.

So:

How old are you: 16-60, 61+
Is this the first time you're applying: Yes / No

If 25-40: you can register online and collect from a bank
If 16-24 or 41+: you can only apply in person

If 16-60+ first application is free
If 60+ always free
If any other age: you need to pay $50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how your data is structured.

Assuming that there is going to be quite a few ages and fruits, some sort of data structure like this would work:

```
  var text = [
  { fruit: "bananas", ages: 
    [
      { range: "18-24", text:"Bananas are awesome"},
      { range: "50-60", text:"Bananas really help with vitamin C and bone density in later life."}
    ]
  },
  { fruit: "apples", ages: 
    [
      {range: "18-24", text:"Apples help you build your immune system at your age!"},
      {range: "50-60", text:"Apples are cheap."}
    ]
   }
]
```

Then the selected value of the select lists can be used to search the data for the right text:

```
function findText(fruit,age)
{
    for(var i =0; i < text.length; i++)
  {
    if(text[i].friut == fruit)
    {
        for(var j=0; j < text[i].ages.length; j++)
      {
        if(text[i].ages[j].range == age)
            return (text[i].ages[j].text;
      }
    }
  }
  return "No match";
}
```

Then how ever you bind the change events just call the find function:

```
document.getElementById("age").onchange = function()
{
  var age= document.getElementById("age").value();
  var fruit = document.getElementById("fruit").value();

  var displayText = fruitText(friut,text);
}
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was looking for, and makes perfect sense. Thank you very much for taking the time - I'll give it a shot ASAP :)